# Importing Images as modules with Rails/React/TypeScript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, typescript, import

I am trying to import an image from the rails asset pipeline which the following code.

```
import avatar_5 from 'images/avatars/avatar_5.png'
```

However, it is not being imported in properly and I am getting this error

> "TS2307: Cannot find module "images/avatars/avatar_5.png".

I have tried importing using this method in .js files, and it works just fine, but with .tsx files, it does not import.

Can anyone help me solve this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Test this: `import avatar_5 from './images/avatars/avatar_5.png'`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this didn't work, I just converted (where possible) the file syntax to .js and then changed the extension back to .js and I was able to get the import to work fine.